# throwing an error in a callback with Swift 3

Tags: ios, error-handling, try-catch, alamofire, swift3

I'm currently using Alamofire for executing an API call:

```
Alamofire.request(baseUrl + path,method:rMethod,parameters:parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers:headers)
            .responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {

                case .success(let data):
                    let json = JSON(data)
                    onCompletion(json, nil)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                    onCompletion(nil,error)
                }
        }
```

Alamofire is notoriously based on a "Result" enum approach for managing the response (check this [article](http://samwize.com/2016/03/09/everything-about-errortype-the-thing-that-swift-throw/)):

```
    public enum Result<T, Error: ErrorType> {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure(Error)
}
```

Now, I would like to migrate to a try/catch approach for managing the error scenario, something like this:

```
Alamofire.request(baseUrl + path,method:rMethod,parameters:parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers:headers)
            .responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {

                case .success(let data):
                    let json = JSON(data)
                    onCompletion(json)
                case .failure(let error):
                    throw error
                }
        }
```

Obviously this approach doesn't work because Alamofire's *responseJSON* function doesn't throw:

```
    /// Adds a handler to be called once the request has finished.
    ///
    /// - parameter options:           The JSON serialization reading options. Defaults to `.allowFragments`.
    /// - parameter completionHandler: A closure to be executed once the request has finished.
    ///
    /// - returns: The request.
    @discardableResult
    public func responseJSON(
        queue: DispatchQueue? = nil,
        options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .allowFragments,
        completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<Any>) -> Void)
        -> Self
    {
        return response(
            queue: queue,
            responseSerializer: DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer(options: options),
            completionHandler: completionHandler
        )
    }
}
```

Question: is there anyway to throw an exception from inside this closure? I have tried forwarding the error to another function which then throw the exception but this is what I get displayed:

[image]

Does this mean that if inside a 3rd party library callback I can never throw an error?

Comment: Instead of the `onCompletion` handler throw the error and mark the enclosing function with `throw`

Comment: I can't mark the enclosing function as throw as I should modify Alamofire callback

Comment: Then wrap the method in another method and `throw` there. Where does `onCompletion` belong to?

Comment: onCompletion belongs to the class which is wrapping Alamofire. I tried to wrap it into another method and throw there the problem persists.

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting correctly your solution. Would you mind to post an answer with some source code? It would help anybody with the same problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: After doing some researches I apologize for being wrong. You cannot mix asynchronous completion handlers with the `throw` pattern.

Comment: no worries, but it's definitely a topic to keep an eye on